# Difference between "addError(ObjectError error)" and "rejectValue(String field, String errorCode)" in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand the difference between:

- **void addError(ObjectError error) (from
  org.springframework.validation.Errors)**
- **void rejectValue(String field,
  errorCode) (from org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)**

I did read the Spring javadocs but could not understand the difference between the two.

Can anyone please provide an explanation or a code sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rejectValue` simply encapsulates the call to addError() providing `ObjectError` or `FieldError` instance.

According to javadoc `addError()` only supports `ObjectError` And `FieldError`, so it's NOT about creating custom ObjectErrors

> void org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.addError(ObjectError error)
>
> Add a custom ObjectError or FieldError to the errors list. 
>   Intended to be used by cooperating strategies such as BindingErrorProcessor.

So `addError()` is more suitable for the framework developers and `rejectValue()` is the way to go.